# How to resolve java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.Exception in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a written unit test case for user validator using spring validator. below is the class.I am facing the issue since in validate method of spring validator, service is called to check whether the user is admin. But admin service throws an exception. So I covered with try catch block. Now for unit test cases I am getting the error.

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
      return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
      User user = (User) target;

      if(user.getName() == null) {
          errors.rejectValue("name", "InValid user");
      }
//try catch block because adminservice throws exeption
      try{
          AdminUser adminUser= adminservice.CheckAdmin(user.getId);
       }

      Catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace
         } 

    }

}

Public uservAlidatorTest(){
@before
//set up done

@test(expected= Exception.class)
public testException(){
User user= new user();
user.setId("JUNK");
mockito.when(adminservice.CheckAdmin(user.getId)).thenThrow(new Exception("Invalid user"))
BindException error = new BindException(User, "user");
UserValidator(user,error); 

}

}
```

error trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.Exception
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Which exception are you trying to catch? Is it all of them? Maybe you actually have bug on a deeper level. What is certain is that with this set, your unit test will always fail. If you need to catch an exception that you know you don't want to consider, then just catch that specific type, although even if you have a known Exception being thrown I would advise you to solve that issue first.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching every single exception from your CheckAdmin call and your unit test expects one. Unless it's thrown before:

> User user = (User) target;
>
> if(user.getName() == null) {
>             errors.rejectValue("name", "InValid user"); }

You will never get any exception and so your unit test will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

In your validator implementation you are swallowing any exception that are being thrown. Even though you are mocking your service method to throw an exception its swallowed in the validator and no exception is thrown in the test. Replace the catch block in your validator as follows

Replace

```
try{
     AdminUser adminUser= adminservice.CheckAdmin(user.getId);
  }
  Catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace
  }
```

with

```
 try{
    AdminUser adminUser= adminservice.CheckAdmin(user.getId);
 }
 Catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
```